# How to make timestamp the same between server and client in firebase?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have a react app which uses firebase cloud functions. On the client side, I use pure javascript `Date.now()` to get the local time (PST timezone) of the client.

On server size, I also try to use the same approach to get the timestamp, but it is in different timezone. This will introduce an issue that if PST time is `8:15pm 12/07/2019`, it will be `4:15am 12/08/2019`, the date is different.

In this case, how can I keep the timestamp consistent between client and server side? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no timezone data encoded into javascript Date objects or Firestore Timestamp object.  Date objects represent time in terms of [unix epoch time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), which represents a specific point in time for all people on the planet.  (Definitely learn what that is if you don't already.)

What you're likely doing is printing a string representation of the date, and it's being formatted the host's configured timezone.  Since you haven't shown any code, it's impossible to say for sure, but it's a fact that Dates don't have a timezone.

If you want to format a date with a specific timezone, you should use a date formatting library that lets you specify which timezone should be represented in the string format.

Comment: Thanks Doug. I mean Date.now() return the timestamp based on PST timezone. But for firebase server side, Date.now() returns the GMT timetamp. If so, can I simply deduct 8 * 60 * 60 * 1000 from Date.now() on the server side to make timestamp consistent?

Comment: Please read my answer again.  There are no timezones encoded in Date object or unix epoch times.  It represents a point in time that's accurate for all people on earth.  If you want to add or subtract time from a unix time, just do the math and it will be OK.

Comment: I got it Doug. I use format() to get the human readable version of the Date object. It translate it to my local time. The format mislead me of the timestamp of the Date. Thanks!!!